# Linking to css files from react index

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I have this simple index :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>SB Admin - Bootstrap Admin Template</title>

<!-- Auth0Lock script -->
<script src="//cdn.auth0.com/js/lock-9.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="/ui/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="/ui/css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="/ui/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

 </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
    </div>
    <script src="/static/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But for some reason, after running npm start, it doesn't get access to the css files.. so i get a page without style. 
Here is the tree of my project:

- actions
- components
- containers
- dist
- middleware
- node_modules
- reducers
- store
- ui
- --css
- --font-awesome
- index.html
- index.js
- webpack.config.js
- package.json

Comment: What do you see in the network tab?

Comment: just this: Warning: Unknown DOM property class. Did you mean className? But it may not be related to this problem.

Comment: What do you see in the _network tab_?

Answer (score 35):

If you want to include css in your html, you gotta put them in your **public** folder and use '%PUBLIC_URL%' as the path to your css. So it would look something like this:

```
<link href="%PUBLIC_URL%/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Alternatively, it is highly recommended that you do import the css that you want inside your react component, because your css would get minified and bundled. So you could do something like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// ... rest of imports
import './path/to/css/font-awesome.min.css'
```

For more info on this, go to the documentation [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#using-the-public-folder).

Comment: I just wonder, how I ignored `Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the public folder during the build.
      Only files inside the public folder can be referenced from the HTML.` in default html file ...