# <i className='fab fa-instagram'></i> is not showing icon properly

Tags: reactjs

import '../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'; 
above the module imported in both index.js and in my component file. How to display icons properly?

Answer (score 1):

your file is a `css` file not a js one so you'll need to import it with the following line

```
<link href="../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

in the `<head>` of your html (not sure about react but AFAIK you have a `index.html`)

if this doesn't work looking at [Linking to css files from react index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44702061/linking-to-css-files-from-react-index) may help you

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core 
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons 
npm i --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome

<FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fab', 'facebook-f']} />
```