# CSS file not properly linking to html when in separate folders

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble linking the css file to the index.html. If it's in the same folder then it works but if I move the CSS file one folder above, it seems to fail even with ../ notation. Here's a picture of the code with the file directory setup.
[Seperate Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaPwB.png)

Shouldn't "../src/index.css" step up a folder, then go down src/ to find the file?

Comment: you need to put href="./../index.css", this should work just tell me if it does

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking to css files from react index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44702061/linking-to-css-files-from-react-index)

Comment: @Ken you can see this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56747558/css-file-not-properly-linking-to-html-when-in-separate-folders..

Comment: just try ./src/index.css

Comment: @PavanNagadiya That doesn't work either unfortunately

Comment: sorry, my friend, I forgot to add one more dote just try ../src/index.css   it's work for me, i just tried it in my system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start your path with the `/` symbol and you'll be using the absolute URL every time. That is, use `href="/src/App.css"` However, it looks like you're using a framework and not plain HTML/CSS. If your files are being compiled into the actual web application, you'll need to use the path for the final output, not the source location, but your framework will provide a variable for this that you tack onto the start of your path instead of the `/`.

(The problem with using relative paths like `../` is that you'll have to change the path for every different level in your file hierarchy, which is a recipe for inconsistency and bugs. The absolute path is the same for every file in your application.)

Comment: I thought React was a library, not a framework, but either way I didn't know HTML/CSS could be compiled. Nor did I know that problem with relative paths. Thank you for the clear explanation! It was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Put your index.css file into public file and add it to your index.html file by using this command

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/../style.css" />
```

You cant put the file at root level and link it from index.html. But in react its best to style by adding separate component.

Comment: If I put index.css into public then it works with just href="index.css". I'm also having this problem when not using React

Comment: ya you cannot access the css from root path thats the main deal here.

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to access it with relative paths?

Answer (score 0):

Get Rid of the `./` and start with `../`

```
../ will take you to the root of your project and the you can traverse to the required file from there.

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../path-to-file.css" />
```

Comment: I tried that in the second image (Problem) but it doesn't work

Comment: In that case you will need to move the css file to the public folder, All your assets like images, css, etc have to be publiclly accessible, 

After moving you can use
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/path-to-file.css" />`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the index.html file using static-server? If yes then go to the root directory and run

```
static-server -i ./public/index.html
```

-i is for providing the index file manually.

If you run static-server in the public folder it doesn't take the css from the root directory.Keep the href as "../index.css". It works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using react and create-react-app correct?  If you are then you cannot access anything outside of that folder from within it because the react environment is built with the public folder as the only publicly accessible folder.

So this is a good place to put an img folder and things like that.  You have 2 choices here.  You can either put your global css file in the public folder and link to it from your html file.  You can also create a css folder in the public folder to store your css files.

Or most people just import the css files into the components.  So for your global css you can just import it in the index.js or app.js files like so:

```
import './index.css'
```

But trying to access anything from a file in your public folder to a file outside of the public folder is a no go.

Comment: I didn't realize the react environment was imposing that limitation, thank you!