# React is not reading my CSS file, why is that?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So I am working on a personal project and trying to add style to my JSX. For some reason, the changes that I am trying to do is not reflected in the result. Everything is linked properly. Did I miss something?

```js
import React from "react"

export default function Header() {
    return (
        <header className="header">
            <img 
                src="./images/troll-face.png" 
                className="header--image"
            />
            <h2 className="header--title">Meme Generator</h2>
            <h4 className="header--project">React Course - Project 3</h4>
        </header>
    )
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Karla", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 65px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #303030 1.18%, #a626d3 100%);
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.header--image {
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.header--title {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.header--project {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla:wght@400;500;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="../src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[here's how my files are arranged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glaW8.png)

[And here is the output in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXdP4.png)

I do not know why the CSS is not reading. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Hey Sarah, If you want to include css in your html, you gotta put them in your public folder and use '%PUBLIC_URL%' as the path to your css. source answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44702061/linking-to-css-files-from-react-index)

Comment: Hi, I tried moving the style.css file to public folder and changed the link to HTML as  <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/style.css" />, however the CSS is still not reflecting.

Comment: can you please [create](https://codesandbox.io/s/) a sandbox example, a [guidline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) about how to create a minimal, Reproducible Example :)

Comment: How you building this? Is it Create React App/Webpack or something like Vite?

Comment: @SarahBarlis import your style file inside the index.js file.